# Reducing wordpress server load, remove or disable plugin?

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on reducing the memory usage on my server.  I currently have 43 active plugins. I've have disabled as much as i can for the woocommerce website to be operational.  I have 70 inactive plugins.  Do i have to delete these plugins or is disabling the plugin enough?  Will inactive plugins add to the memory usage?

Answer (score 1):

Inactive plugins wont slow down your website. But for 70 inactive plugins you may feel a little slow down in your admin area only (not at front end). But keep in mind to update all plugins even though they are inactive. Outdated plugins might cause security risk.

And there is a plugin called [p3 profiler](https://wordpress.org/plugins/p3-profiler/). It will analyze which plugin is using more load.